# Error when getting QDomElement value in a QString

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, memory

I have this C++ code in which I try to get value form an XML file through QDomDocument api:

```
        ...
        QFile xml_file("file.xml");
        QDomDocument qdom_document;
        maps_qdom_document.setContent(&maps_xml_file);
        QDomNodeList maps = qdom_document.elementsByTagName("map");
        QDomNode n = maps.item(0);
        QDomElement markers_list = n.firstChildElement("markers_list");
        QDomNodeList markers = markers_list.elementsByTagName("marker");
        QDomNode marker;
        int  _id;
        QString value1;
        for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
            marker = markers.item(i);

            // APPLICATION STOPS AT THE LINE BELOW
            value1 = marker.firstChildElement("id").text(); //!!!ERROR DETECTED HERE
            _id = value1.toInt();
        }
        ...
```

testing the value value1 it is defined and contains the value that I want ( I convert it to std::string and read it )

[Error Detected when getting value1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DlFn.png)

this is the call Stack when the program stops at the line described:

[Call Stack on the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Ov9.png)

and this the natvis output:

```
Natvis: C:\USERS\USER\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0\EXTENSIONS\BFMZ1AIF.2DM\natvis\qt5.natvis(200,25): Error: class "QString::Data" has no member "offset"
Error while evaluating '((reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub' in the context of type 'main.exe!QString'.
```

I use Visual Studio 2015 and the compiler vsc10 (of visual studio 2010). I use the QT VS Addin which is best used for Qt 5 but I configure it with Qt4.8 librairies.

I searched in the net, and found that is a memory problem ( delete a deleted variable or something like that) but I didn't find the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem of this behavior. It was because the version of Qt VS Addin is only supports Qt5 or later. Since my project is linking with Qt 4.8, it produces some errors like this. After upgrading my Qt version to 5.5, this problem disappears.